# Trying to bind xm+ to tx12 radiomaster

Tags: first-person-view, receiver, frsky, firmware, frsky-xm+

Hello I am trying to bind xm+ to a radiomaster tx12 w cc2500 mode inside ive tried rolling back the firmware on the xm+ but to no prevail. Also tied version 2 with frsky x2 (d16) Nothing seems to be working I am wondering what firmware I should be using on the radiomaster for it? any tips will help thanks
Ive tried xm+Accst_2.1.2_fcc_rssi. And tried old version xm+Fcc170313-rssi16.frk
None seem to work